# date_select to current and past month select only in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in form i used `date_select` but by default it adds all month of year. i am able to restrict year to current and past year but i am not able to restrict month. i want when user select 2020 they won't see September in there drop-down.

here is my current code-

```
<div class="field medium-4 columns">
   <%= form.label :attendance_month %>
   <%= form.date_select :attendance_month, { :discard_day => true, :discard_month => false, :discard_year => false, :end_year => Time.now.year },:class => 'month-and-year' %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [date_select](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/date_select) you have only the option of restricting the year but not the month and day.

Either you can add model validation on date and raise error. Or you can use [jQuery Date Picker](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker) plugin and set [minDate](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate) and [maxDate](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate) options to restrict the date range.